# EclipseLink @OneToMany relationship size JPQL exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, glassfish, wildfly, jboss-arquillian

I try to deploy my java ee application that has been working fine on Wildly/Hibernate to GlassFish/EclipseLink and I'm getting such error:

```
Problem compiling [DELETE FROM ProviderService ps WHERE :work_station MEMBER OF ps.workStations AND ps.workStations.size = 1].
[81, 101] The state field path 'ps.workStations.size' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
 81, 101] The state field path 'ps.workStations.size' cannot be resolved to a valid type.
```

Is there possibility to run glass fish with hibernate? And if so how could i configure such thing in build.gradle.

I'am using in build.gradle conditional selection of Wildfly remote/Wildfly embedded for testing with Arquillian (works ok), and now adding Glassfish remote/Glassfish embedded but here I couldn't compile there is such error as above. I receive also something like this:

```
    ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ArquillianServletRunner not found. Could not determine ContextRoot from ProtocolMetadata, please contact DeployableContainer developer.
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.ServletUtil.determineBaseURI
```

Comment: Presumably "ps.workStations" is a collection? so what is this "size" field? If you mean "size" to be a FUNCTION then this page shows them http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/jpql.html#functions    perhaps "SIZE(ps.workStations)"

Comment: yes its collection and i think i have been using size as this is allowed property in Hibernate? (It works then correctly)

Comment: I don't see the relevance of Hibernate here, it is EclipseLink, and the JPA spec is very clear ... you use a function "SIZE(field)" ... hence why you get the error using invalid JPQL syntax.

Comment: What about using Glassfish/EclipseLink/Jersey and WildFly/Hibernate/RestEasy when developing RESTful web service I would like to test on both environments... I have been developing in WilfFly but trying to migrate to Glassfish in order to be able to use MVC 1.0 Ozark future implementation

Comment: What about GlassFish? That is not the question here ... which says "EclipseLink @OneToMany relationship size JPQL exception". If you have other questions you raise them as separate questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JPQL is invalid. JPQL is defined by the JPA spec and for portability you have to stick to the correct syntax. In this case there is a FUNCTION "`SIZE`". Should be

```
DELETE FROM ProviderService ps WHERE :work_station MEMBER OF ps.workStations AND SIZE(ps.workStations) = 1
```